# MVC/JQuery keepalive / heartbeat - not working?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have seen some examples of using JQuery to keep a session alive by using `$.post` to post to a .html file. This code is in the `_Layout.cshtml` file.

Here's the code I'm using:

```js
$(function () {

   // Keep alive with a call every minute
   window.setInterval("keepSessionAlive()", 60000);

   function keepSessionAlive() {
        console.log("beat!");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "heartbeat.html",
            success: function () {
                console.log("success");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("fail");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here are my questions:

1. I believe that this is keeping the session alive just by doing a `POST`. Is this correct?
2. Why is it hitting the error function and not success? Is it because my html file is just a comment, or is the POST not able to find my html file? The file is in both _Shared and Views folders, and is included in my project.

Comment: What does the fiddler log say regarding the response sent from the server?

Comment: You can not HTTP POST to an html page. Check Network tab of your browser to  view the error you are getting.

Comment: @CleanCrispCode: Why do you think that an HTML page can not be requested using POST?

Comment: @Guffa - I have created an html page in my MVC application , and tried HTTP  POST from fiddler , I got 405 , method not supported , whereas for HTTP GET , it works fine.

Comment: @Guffa this link explains about 405 , http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html

Comment: @CleanCrispCode: Just because that application didn't handle a POST request for that specific HTML file, doesn't mean that it can't be done.

Comment: The reason your getting the error is because the MVC engine is tying to call  a method called "heartbeat" and them looking for a view "heartbeat" in home/heartbeat. First create heartbeat as a view in the home folder then in the home controller create an actionResult called heartbeat that returns the view heartbeat. Last in your script the url should be just "heartbeat".

Comment: @CleanCrispCode I've just had that 405 returned. If I change the code to GET instead of POST will that keep the session alive?

Comment: @VictorySaber - Yes , it should . In case if it does not keep it alive , then try the GET for a controller instead of html file

Answer (score 0):

> I believe that this is keeping the session alive just by doing a POST.
>   am I correct?

Well, yes and no. The session is kept alive by the server handling the request, not by the browser sending the request, so the request has to work properly to keep the session alive.

> Why is it hitting the error case and not success? Is it because my
>   html file is just a comment, or is the POST not able to find my html
>   file?

The response isn't evaluated, so it's not because it's just a comment.

The error is because the server could not handle the request, most likely because the file was not found. You should use the network view in the developer tools in the browser to see what the actual error message is that the server sends.